# Brownian motion does not diverge in finite time

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $B_t$ be a $1$-dimensional standard Brownian motion and the stopping time $\tau_a$ is $\tau_a:=\inf\{t>0:|B_t|\geq a\}$ for $a>0$. Then,$\lim_{a\to\infty}\tau_a=\infty$ almost surely.

Why is this? I think this is definitely fundamental, but I can not prove. 
Can someone please give me some clues? Thanks!

Comment: I note that one-dimesional Brownian motion is [recurrent](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math56aS08/Math56a_S08_notes085.pdf) for every point on the line.  This is absolutely not true in three or more dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the very definition of the stopping times, $\tau_a(\omega)$ is increasing in $a$ for each fixed $\omega$. This means that

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \tau_a(\omega)=\sup_{a>0} \tau_a(\omega)$$

exists for all $\omega \in \Omega$. If the supremum were finite for some $\omega \in \Omega$, say, $\sup_{a>0} \tau_a(\omega)=T<\infty$, then $$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |B_t(\omega)| = \infty.$$ This means that $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ cannot be continuous (otherwise it would be bounded on the compact set $[0,T]$). Since the sample paths of Brownian motion are continuous (with probability $1$), this means that $\sup_{a>0} \tau_a(\omega)<\infty$ can only happen on a null set. Hence, $\sup_{a>0} \tau_a(\omega)=\infty$ almost surely.

Finally, to prove that $\tau_a(\omega)<\infty$ with probability $1$, we can use a martingale argument. Since $(B_t^2-t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, it follows from the optional stopping theorem that

$$\mathbb{E}(B_{t \wedge \tau_a}^2-(t \wedge \tau_a))=0.$$

Using $|B_{t \wedge \tau_a}| \leq a$ we get

$$\mathbb{E}(\tau_a \wedge t) \leq a^2.$$

By monotone convergence,

$$\mathbb{E}(\tau_a) \leq a^2 < \infty,$$

and in particular $\tau_a<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Excellent answer @saz, but was the claim that $\tau_a(\omega)<\infty$ a.s. part of the original question?

Comment: Also I believe the $\tau$ in your $B^2_{t\wedge \tau}$ should be a $\tau_a$, correct?

Comment: @saz Thanks! This proof is easy to understand. Now I get it.

Comment: @Math1000 Not sure whether it's part of the actual problem, but the title of the question somehow suggests that it is relevant for the OP. (In any case, the proof is not very long, so I just added it). And yes, $\tau$ should be $\tau_a$; I will fix it in a minute.